# Angular turn Observable into an array

Tags: angular

I'm making a gallery of images in Angular. On click on each image I want to display separate component which is basically clicked image but in full size. Porblem is I'm not sure how to get image which is clicked.

So far I have this service to make API request to get images.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  images = [];
  link = 'https://api.com?k=';
  ApiKey = '12345';

  public loadImages() {
    return this.http.get(this.link + this.ApiKey);
  }
}
```

Then I have Gallery Component where I subscribe to `loadImages()`

```
export class GalleryComponent {
   visibleImages:Object = [];

  constructor(private imagesService: ImagesService) {
    this.imagesService.loadImages().subscribe(data => this.visibleImages = data);
   }
}
```

Then in HTML of Gallery component I display images like this

```
<li *ngFor="let image of visibleImages">
  <a [routerLink]="['/image', image.id]">
    <img src="{{image.urls.small}}"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

So the problem is how to get clicked image? I thought about something like this in my service. But this problem that is how can I store data which I get from API to `this.images`? Plus as I understand the response which I'm getting back is an Observable so I can't really store it into an array?

```
getImage(id:number) {
    this.images.slice(0).filter(image => image.id == id);
  }
```

And in Image component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.image = this.imagesService.getImage(+this.route.snapshot.params['id'])
  }
```

Comment: don't expose your api key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `do` operator to intercept the data :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  images = [];
  link = 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=';
  ApiKey = 'your key';

  public loadImages() {
    return this
      .http.get(this.link + this.ApiKey)
      .do((images: any[]) => this.images = images)
  }

  getImage(id:number) {
    this.images.slice(0).filter(image => image.id == id);
  }
}
```

if the ImageComponent is in the same page as GalleryComponent you have to subscribe to the `this.route.params` :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params  => this.image = this.imagesService.getImage(+params['id']))
  }
```